# trim canvas on drawimage keeping center of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to write an HTML5 app to take a photo for an ID card via webcam.

Here is the camera presented to the potential picture taker:

[image]

idea being the camera is 300x225 and the end result is the inside of the red box (170x200)

using what i thought i learned about `drawImage()` from this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [html5canvastutorials.com](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/html5-canvas-image-crop-diagram.png))</sub>

i produced this code:

`drawImage(video, 65, 12, 170, 200, 0, 0, 170, 200);`

in my mind this means start clipping at 65px, 12px, the clip 170px, 200px,. this is clearly not right because its producing this:

[image]

so i got the 170x200 down, but its still starting from the top left of the picture?

**tl;dr**: how would i trim out the 170x200 centered box from a 300x225 canvas?

Comment: are your coordinates x, y at 0, 0? maybe you should move them from the left and top sides? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp - the 6, 7 parameters

Comment: @rustam the 0,0 is where it places the drawn image on the canvas. that is like, the only part that is actually working exactly how i expect it to be working.

Comment: you want to put your image at the center of your canvas? if I understand right

Comment: @rustam i want to draw only whats inside the red box (170x200) on the video onto the canvas (which is also 170x200, so place the image at 0x0).

Comment: what if you use drawImage(video, 0, 0)? cause this 2 parameters define where to start cliping , the first picture in your question is the full picture, can I test it?

Comment: @rustam i figured out it was an issue with the video. so i drew the video in fullsize as an image on a hidden canvas, then trimmed the image out of the hidden canvas onto a new, smaller canvas. this worked fine. who the hell knows why.